# Separating superimposed images based on color

Tags: opencv, image-processing, rgb, stereo-3d

I have a stereo camera which combines both the left and right views into this singular image. Although each camera is a different color, left is green, and right is magenta. How can I separate this image into two separate images. Using Python, opencv, numpy, etc.

Stereo camera combines both left and right images:

[image: 1]

Comment: the pixels of your image, plotted in a RGB cube, show a plane stretching between the Green axis and the Red+Blue axis (a diagonal), so your data is really 2-channel. however, I don't see a good clean way to separate two usable pictures out of that. further, your image has saturated parts. those will leave artefacts.

Comment: Do you have some details on the camera that you are using? Where did you got it from? Any product name, product description, manual? Any original purpose, filter specs that should be used for viewing etc?

Answer (score 0):

you only need to extract the color components.
Channel Red+blue = right image
Channel Green = left image.
you can do it with any photo editor like Photoshop or GIMP.
see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046265/extract-one-channel-image-from-rgb-image-with-opencv) to see how to do it with opencv.

[image: green channel]
[image: red and blue channels]

Comment: grayscale filter and brightness adjust can improve visibility